# Whats the difference between "id" and "stream_id" in the structure returned with the option "PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE" by the "perf_event_open" syscall?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, perf

I am trying to write a piece of code using the `perf_event_open` syscall. But I don't understand the real difference between `id` and `stream_id` fields in the structure returned in my memory map.

---

This structure is like this one (from the man page of `perf_event_open`) :

```
struct {
          struct perf_event_header header;
          u64    sample_id;   /* if PERF_SAMPLE_IDENTIFIER */
          u64    ip;          /* if PERF_SAMPLE_IP */
          u32    pid, tid;    /* if PERF_SAMPLE_TID */
          u64    time;        /* if PERF_SAMPLE_TIME */
          u64    addr;        /* if PERF_SAMPLE_ADDR */
          u64    id;          /* if PERF_SAMPLE_ID */
          u64    stream_id;   /* if PERF_SAMPLE_STREAM_ID */
          u32    cpu, res;    /* if PERF_SAMPLE_CPU */
          u64    period;      /* if PERF_SAMPLE_PERIOD */
          struct read_format v;
                                          /* if PERF_SAMPLE_READ */
          u64    nr;          /* if PERF_SAMPLE_CALLCHAIN */
          u64    ips[nr];     /* if PERF_SAMPLE_CALLCHAIN */
          u32    size;        /* if PERF_SAMPLE_RAW */
          char  data[size];   /* if PERF_SAMPLE_RAW */
          u64    bnr;         /* if PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_STACK */
          struct perf_branch_entry lbr[bnr];
                                          /* if PERF_SAMPLE_BRANCH_STACK */
          u64    abi;         /* if PERF_SAMPLE_REGS_USER */
          u64    regs[weight(mask)];
                                          /* if PERF_SAMPLE_REGS_USER */
          u64    size;        /* if PERF_SAMPLE_STACK_USER */
          char   data[size];  /* if PERF_SAMPLE_STACK_USER */
          u64    dyn_size;    /* if PERF_SAMPLE_STACK_USER &&
                                             size != 0 */
          u64    weight;      /* if PERF_SAMPLE_WEIGHT */
          u64    data_src;    /* if PERF_SAMPLE_DATA_SRC */
          u64    transaction; /* if PERF_SAMPLE_TRANSACTION */
          u64    abi;         /* if PERF_SAMPLE_REGS_INTR */
          u64    regs[weight(mask)];
                                          /* if PERF_SAMPLE_REGS_INTR */
          };
```

The man page give me this explanation :

```
id               If PERF_SAMPLE_ID is enabled, a 64-bit unique ID is included.  If the event is a member of an event group, the group leader ID is returned.  This ID is the same as the one returned by PERF_FORMAT_ID.
stream_id        If PERF_SAMPLE_STREAM_ID is enabled, a 64-bit unique ID is included. Unlike PERF_SAMPLE_ID the actual ID is returned, not the group leader.  This ID is the same as the one returned by PERF_FORMAT_ID.
```

But the problem is here: the documentation seems to be incoherent.

Have I missed something ?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: [The man7.org has a different description](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html)

Comment: No, it's the same description look at this position : MMAP Layout -> PERF_RECORD_SAMPLE -> id           I think you didn't look at the right place.

Comment: So it seems, it seems that a different text is provided above that for descriptions of the meanings of `PERF_SAMPLE_ID` and `PERF_SAMPLE_STREAM_ID`

Comment: Hum.. If I understand, you tell me that one give me an arbitrary unique ID wich is the same for the vent group, and another one give me only the ID of the event leader ?  Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the presence of `PERF_SAMPLE_STREAM_ID` is to maintain event IDs of inherited counters. While the `PERF_SAMPLE_ID` will contain the event ID of the parent counters. (if there is any parent-child relationship).

Inherited counters are those counters which are allotted to child tasks, originating from the parent task which is being profiled (unless the flag `--no-inherit` is being passed to `perf` command).

This detail is described in this old [commit](https://git.kontron-electronics.de/linux/linux-imx-exceet/commit/7f453c24b95a085fc7bd35d53b33abc4dc5a048b).

Looking at the latest source code [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.5/source/kernel/events/core.c#L6411),

```
if (sample_type & (PERF_SAMPLE_ID | PERF_SAMPLE_IDENTIFIER))
        data->id = primary_event_id(event);

    if (sample_type & PERF_SAMPLE_STREAM_ID)
        data->stream_id = event->id;

....

/*
 * If we inherit events we want to return the parent event id
 * to userspace.
 */
static u64 primary_event_id(struct perf_event *event)
{
    u64 id = event->id;

    if (event->parent)
        id = event->parent->id;

    return id;
}
```

The above snippet of code clearly distinguishes between the two members of the structure. This is irrespective of whether the event is a group leader or not.

Also, it is important to note that, all the events in a group will also compute/use this `primary_event_id` function.  This can be seen [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.5/source/kernel/events/core.c#L4921). So, all the events in a group will contain the id of the group leader.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the snippet. What is the "perf_event" struct ? What is its "parent" member ?

Comment: And I don't understand your explanation of ```PERF_SAMPLE_STREAM_ID``` and ```PERF_SAMPLE_ID``` too. I think an example will be clearer, if you have time.